# Variables not expended inside ansible.builtin.include_vars

Tags: ansible

I have this following file var/Hendrix.yml

```
    last: Hendrix
    fullname: "Jimi {{ last }}"
```

And the following playbook

```
    - name:
      hosts: localhost
      tasks:
        - name: include
          include_vars: "{{ choice }}.yml"
    
        - name: debug
          debug:
            msg: "include_vars {{ choice }}, {{ fullname }}"
      tags: simpleinc

    - name:
      hosts: localhost
      tags: builtininc
      tasks:
        - name: include
          ansible.builtin.include_vars:
            file: "{{ choice }}.yml"
    
        - name: debug
          debug:
            msg: "ansible.builtin.include_vars {{ choice }}, {{ fullname }}"
```

running with tags simpleinc or builtininc does not show the same result

`ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-vars "choice=Hendrix" --tags simpleinc`

```
    TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "msg": "include_vars Hendrix, Jimi Hendrix"
    }
```

`ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-vars "choice=Hendrix" --tags builtininc`

```
    TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "msg": "ansible.builtin.include_vars Hendrix, Jimi {{ last }}"
    }
```

I read that using full name of task is a good practice, but here it puzzeld me a bit, maybe this is due to `file` parameter, but I don't see any `template`

Comment: What is your Ansible version?

Comment: I use ansible 2.9.6

Comment: I cannot reproduce, on the version 2.9.6 I just installed, the files in the _default_ folder of the role are not something I use in `include_vars`, though, the files have to be in the _vars_ folder of the role.

Comment: It's a mess. You say `"Will use java version 17.0.3"` where `java_version` is `17.0.3`. At the same time, you include file `java-{{ java_version }}.yml`. But the name of the file is `java-1_17.yml`.

Comment: @VladimirBotka good point, I updated my description

Comment: I completely rewrote the description to pin point my issue, thanks @β.εηοιτ.βε to raise my curiosity

Comment: Mhm, honestly, this is probably a bug, but since 2.9 is EOL, there is probably nothing you'll be able to do about it.